# How to calculate Lennard-Jones potential for a crystalline material?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, computational-physics, crystals, interactions

Suppose that we have the unit cell of a crystalline material. We want to calculate the Lennard-Jones (LJ) interaction energy between an hydrogen atom at a point $\mathbf{r}$ (inside the unit cell) with all the atoms of the material.

Since LJ potential decreases very rapidly, **can I consider only the atoms inside a sphere of radius $r_\text{cut}$ to calculate the potential?** Of course, these atoms might be periodic images of the atoms in the unit cell.

That is, is the following formula:

$$
V(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{i: |\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}| \leq r_\text{cut}} \text{LJ (H, atom i)}
$$
valid, assuming sufficient large $r_{\text{rcut}}$ (e.g. 10 angstroms)?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the cutoff to $2.5\sigma$, so I guess if you are using roughly standard values of the radius $\sigma \sim 0.34$ nm then your choice should be fine.